# Mybatis - error occurred during closing connection

Tags: java, oracle, mybatis

I'm using mybatis connect to oracle.

My mybatis config is:

```
<settings>
    <setting name="lazyLoadingEnabled" value="true" />
    <setting name="aggressiveLazyLoading" value="false" />
    <setting name="logImpl" value="${logImpl}" />
    <setting name="defaultStatementTimeout" value="10" />
</settings>
<environments default="default">
    <environment id="default">
        <transactionManager type="JDBC" />
        <dataSource type="POOLED">
            <property name="driver" value="${jdbc.driver}" />
            <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
            <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
            <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
            <property name="poolPingConnectionsNotUsedFor" value="290000"/>
            <property name="poolPingQuery" value="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM RESORT"/>
            <property name="poolPingEnabled" value="true"/>
        </dataSource>
    </environment>
</environments>
```

My code of open session is like

```
SqlSession sqlSession = factory.openSession();
Object result = null;
try
{
    QueryInfoMapper mapper = sqlSession.getMapper(QueryInfoMapper.class);
    result = mapper.queryInfoFromOpera(mybatisMapping);
} finally
{
    sqlSession.close();
}
```

*Because of application scoped of the class, and sqlSession could not be used in application scope, so I have to manage sqlSession by myself.*

The log is

> 2019-04-11 15:30:35,773 INFO  [stdout] (default task-60) Opening JDBC Connection
>
> 2019-04-11 15:30:41,860 INFO  [stdout] (default task-57) Bad connection. Could not roll back
>
> 2019-04-11 15:30:41,861 INFO  [stdout] (default task-57) Claimed overdue connection 962608913.
>
> 2019-04-11 15:30:41,861 INFO  [stdout] (default task-57) A bad connection (962608913) was returned from the pool, getting another connection.
>
> 2019-04-11 15:30:41,895 INFO  [stdout] (default task-57) Created connection 1812494479.
>
> 2019-04-11 15:30:41,895 INFO  [stdout] (default task-57) Setting autocommit to false on JDBC Connection [oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@6c08788f]
>
> 2019-04-11 15:30:41,895 INFO  [stdout] (default task-57) ==>  Preparing: SELECT TRAVEL_AGENT_NAME FROM( SELECT TRAVEL_AGENT_NAME FROM OPERA.NAME_RESERVATION WHERE RESV_NAME_ID = ? ) WHERE ROWNUM = 1
>
> 2019-04-11 15:30:41,896 INFO  [stdout] (default task-57) ==> Parameters: 288541(String)
>
> 2019-04-11 15:30:41,900 INFO  [stdout] (default task-57) <==    Columns: TRAVEL_AGENT_NAME
>
> 2019-04-11 15:30:41,900 INFO  [stdout] (default task-57) <==        Row: null
>
> 2019-04-11 15:30:41,900 INFO  [stdout] (default task-57) <==      Total: 1
>
> 2019-04-11 15:30:41,900 INFO  [stdout] (default task-57) Resetting autocommit to true on JDBC Connection [oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@6c08788f]
>
> 2019-04-11 **15:30:41**,900 INFO  [stdout] (default task-57) **Closing JDBC Connection** [oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@6c08788f]
>
> 2019-04-11 **15:31:00**,788 INFO  [stdout] (default task-60) **Bad connection. Could not roll back**
>
> 2019-04-11 15:31:00,788 INFO  [stdout] (default task-60) Claimed overdue connection 1228464923.
>
> 2019-04-11 15:31:00,788 INFO  [stdout] (default task-60) A bad connection (1228464923) was returned from the pool, getting another connection.
>
> 2019-04-11 15:31:00,820 INFO  [stdout] (default task-60) Created connection 265625885.
>
> 2019-04-11 15:31:00,820 INFO  [stdout] (default task-60) Setting autocommit to false on JDBC Connection [oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@fd5211d]
>
> 2019-04-11 15:31:00,820 INFO  [stdout] (default task-57) Returned connection 1812494479 to pool.

Seeing the log, according to the timestamp, it seems happens during closing connection(which is transaction here)

But it takes 9s or 19s to close it. The second log is "Bad connection. Could not roll back". I can't locate where is the really cause. And which method takes so much time. This issue doesn't happen every time but randomly.

I thought to set `<property name="poolMaximumActiveConnections" value="40" />` to increase connections. I'm not sure if it would help.

What would be the cause of failed to close connection/transaction? How can I avoid the failed of closing connection/transaction?

===========================

Update: I met this issue again and log comes something different:

> 2019-04-13 15:42:31,812 INFO  [stdout] (default task-86) Opening JDBC Connection
>
> 2019-04-13 15:42:35,493 INFO  [stdout] (default task-62) Execution of ping query 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM RESORT' failed: IO Error: Socket read timed out
>
> 2019-04-13 15:42:35,493 INFO  [stdout] (default task-62) Connection 1963609369 is BAD: IO Error: Socket read timed out
>
> 2019-04-13 15:42:35,493 INFO  [stdout] (default task-62) A bad connection (1963609369) was returned from the pool, getting another connection.
>
> 2019-04-13 15:42:35,493 INFO  [stdout] (default task-62) Checked out connection 195963529 from pool.
>
> 2019-04-13 15:42:35,493 INFO  [stdout] (default task-62) Testing connection 195963529 ...
>
> 2019-04-13 15:42:54,448 INFO  [stdout] (default task-62) Execution of ping query 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM RESORT' failed: IO Error: Socket read timed out
>
> 2019-04-13 15:42:54,448 INFO  [stdout] (default task-62) Connection 195963529 is BAD: IO Error: Socket read timed out
>
> 2019-04-13 15:42:54,448 INFO  [stdout] (default task-62) A bad connection (195963529) was returned from the pool, getting another connection.
>
> 2019-04-13 15:42:54,479 INFO  [stdout] (default task-62) Created connection 741137137.

Btw, I'll change the ping sql to `SELECT 1 FROM DUAL`.
What could cause this socket read timed out?

Comment: Your `poolPingQuery` of `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM RESORT` is potentially very expensive, and considering that a pool ping query gets called to check whether everything is ok with a connection, having an expensive query is not recommended - have you considered using `SELECT 1 FROM DUAL` which would not need to access a table?

Answer (score 2):

I can see several problems here:

1. potentially heavy ping query (as pointed by [beny23](https://stackoverflow.com/users/227140/beny23))
2. long close connection operation
3. incorrect behaviour of the mybatis connection pool

You definitely need to use `SELECT 1 FROM DUAL` as a ping query. Otherwise you a doing some not so cheap operation on every connection open.

The long close and `IO Error: Socket read timed out` suggests that there is either some network connectivity issue or oracle server availability issue or both.

It makes sense to check oracle healthiness at the time when this issue happens. Does it respond to other queries at that time? What is the CPU/io/memory/swap usage etc. If the server is under very high load it may be that it does not respond in time.

Checking the issues with network connectivity is a very broad topic. The most reliable (and also complex) way I know is to capture network traffic (with tools like tcpdump or WireShark) on both ends and compare them.

Then there's an issue with mybatis connection pool.

First of all some background about how mybatis connection pool works.

One important and not obvious thing is that mybatis connection pool implementation forcefully returns connections to the pool if they are used for too long. Here's the quote from the [documentation](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/configuration.html):

> poolMaximumCheckoutTime – This is the amount of time that a Connection can be "checked out" of the pool before it will be forcefully returned. Default: 20000ms (i.e. 20 seconds)

It means that if the application tries to open new connection and all connections are busy then mybatis will close the oldest connection if it was in use for more than 20 seconds (by default).

It is by itself may be a very unexpected behaviour if you have some long running queries. Another and probably bigger problem is how this is implemented in mybatis. In order to grab a connection the [request to rollback](https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/ibatis/datasource/pooled/PooledDataSource.java#L419) the transaction is done from the thread which requested new connection (In the example above thread `default task-57` is holding the connection and thread `default task-60` tries to get the connection from the pool).

This is the problem because oracle jdbc driver [requires](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/java.102/b14355/apxtips.htm#i1005436) proper synchronization when accessing the connection from multiple threads and mybatis does not do that:

> Controlled serial access to a connection, such as that provided by connection caching, is both necessary and encouraged. However, Oracle strongly discourages sharing a database connection among multiple threads. Avoid allowing multiple threads to access a connection simultaneously. If multiple threads must share a connection, use a disciplined begin-using/end-using protocol.

So this failure to synchronize access from multiple thread to the shared resource (the connection) may cause all kinds of consistency problems and I do not exclude the possibility that the problem with closing the connection is caused by the fact that connection had gotten into some inconsistent state earlier because of the lack of the synchronization.

Increasing the pool size removes this problem for the given load as the situation when the pool is exhausted does not happen (or happens less frequently).

Note that concurrency issues are very tricky to reproduce and positive synthetic test gives you virtually no guarantee. This a broad topic so recommend you to look to [Goetz book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321349601) for details.

I would change the connection pool implementation, namely use https://github.com/swaldman/c3p0 or https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/ or https://brettwooldridge.github.io/HikariCP/.

Comment: Hi Roman, considering your explaination, I open session each time of querying. I've also done concurrent test and no issue. What would be the reason failed to creating connection? I've also updated the new exception log. Would there be oracle has no more connection to use?

Comment: I've updated my answer. It does not matter when you open the session. If the pool is used from multiple threads and you ever need to serve more requests than the pool size the pool will forcefully rollback connections. The test may not show the existing concurrency problem.

Comment: Hi Roman, Thank you very much about the explain. I start 50 threads to invoke the api 5 times each and no issue. I also check the connections created to oracle is more than 5, but reduce to 5 when concurrency test finished. The issue happens when we don't invoke the api for about 10 or 20 minutes. Which means the connection can't be idle for a long time. Does oracle have a rule to recycle not used connections? "connection had gotten into some inconsistent state earlier", I doubt oracle destroy the connection while mybatis still cache the connection in pool.

Comment: So when mybatis ping `SELECT count(*) FROM RESORT` to oracle, the connection has gone. And `"defaultStatementTimeout" value="10" ` waits for 10s. Mybatis gets exception and create new connection, the aim SQL runs. Does this guess hold water?

Comment: I change `POOL` to `UNPOOL` and retest my api, no matter how much time interval, the issue doesn't appear. I know `UNPOOL` is very expensive. If I can't uniformize mybatis and oracle connection status, what should I do?

Comment: Using no pool at all is definitely a bad idea. I've updated the answer with details what I meant by `change the connection pool implementation`. Secondly, I've added details about concurrency testing as well.